# как вычислить разницу между двумя полями в Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

на **SQL**:

```
SELECT lastTime - firstTime as result FROM times;
```

Как запрос будет выглядеть в **Elasticsearch**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего использовать [script_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) в запросе

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "result": {
            "script": "doc['lastTime'].value - doc['firstTime'].value"
        }
    }
}
```

Математическое действие будет произведено только при условии что оба поля типа integer или float. В противном случае конкатенация. Проверьте маппинг.